Auth0 Expo, user is logged in but it is null from useAuth0()
I'm creating app with expo (react-native).
I decided to use auth0, and followed this tutorial.
It works with Blank project, but whenever I try to do auth with file based routing it does not work.
I have simple default project structure that comes from "default" project type when the one creates project with expo.
I created 3 components from tutorial:

const Profile = () => {
  const {user, error} = useAuth0();

  return (
      <>
          {user && <Text>Logged in as {user?.name}</Text>}
          {!user && <Text>Not logged in</Text>}
          {error && <Text>{error.message}</Text>}
      </>
  )
}

const LoginButton = () => {
  const {authorize} = useAuth0();

  const onPress = async () => {
      try {
          await authorize();
      } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
      }
  };

  return <Button onPress={onPress} title="Log in" />
}

const LogoutButton = () => {
  const {clearSession} = useAuth0();

  const onPress = async () => {
      try {
          await clearSession();
      } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
      }
  };

  return <Button onPress={onPress} title="Log out" />
}

Then I created /app/(auth)/sign-in.tsx that has basicaly these components(LoginButton, LogoutButton, Profile), and put them in /app/(tabs)/index.tsx as well.
(I'm showing profile for visibility)
<LoginButton />
<LogoutButton />
<Profile />


And crucial moment I put auth protection the same way I would do it in regular react app in app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx:
 const { user, error, isLoading } = useAuth0();

  if (isLoading) {
    return <ThemedText> Loading</ThemedText>
  }

  if (!user) {
    console.log('user is not found')
    console.log("errlr", error)
    return <Redirect href="/sign-in" />
  }

I have wrapped with correct domain and client id the app/_layout.tsx
<Auth0Provider domain={"domain.eu.auth0.com"} clientId={"clientid"}>
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" />
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>
    </Auth0Provider>

THE problem:
I'm getting to sign in screen, I see Not logged in. Then I click on Log In button, it redirects me to auth0 screen, I am successfully authorizing via Google, no errors, nothing, and then I got to be redirected to /app/(tabs)/index.tsx.
There my user is null, error is null and isLoading is false (I'm logging it). So I am getting redirected back to /app/(auth)/sign-in.tsx, and I see "Logged in as Andrii".
So somehow on the (tabs) it cannot capture user, and in (auth) it can, however it comes from the same hook, in the same nesting, with the same components.
I will appreciate any reply or help.
